# Is it possible to use cucumber with gradle buildship in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, cucumber

I'm trying to compile a "hello world" Cucumber application using the Gradle buildship in Eclipse.  When I try to run it (choosing 'build') in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
   Launching gradle tasks failed due to an error connecting to the gradle 
   build.  Could not execute build using gradle distribution 
   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip

   Some build operations have not been marked as completed
```

I can successfully build using the command line using the same configuration:

```
   :compileJava
   :processResources NO-SOURCE
   :classes
   :jar
   :assemble
   :compileTestJava
   :processTestResources
   :testClasses
   :test

   skeleton.RunCukesTest STANDARD_OUT
       ...waiting...
       ...growling...

       1 Scenarios (1 passed)
       3 Steps (3 passed)
       0m0.085s

   :check
   :build

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL

   Total time: 3.19 secs
```

and here is the version info for the command line:

C:\Users\whalen\Documents\ws\workspace\Cucumber-hello-world>gradlew -version

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  Gradle 3.5
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  Build time:   2017-04-10 13:37:25 UTC
  Revision:     b762622a185d59ce0cfc9cbc6ab5dd22469e18a6

  Groovy:       2.4.10
  Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
  JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
  OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Any ideas on what might be preventing the build from succeeding on Gradle buildship would be greatly appreciated!